# Prevent Firefox or Chrome from evaluating URLs before page request?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, directory-traversal

If you browse to this page:

```
http://192.168.10.8/../../../../../windows/win.ini
```

Firefox/Chrome will evaluate the URL first. The resulting page requested will be:

```
http://192.168.10.8/windows/win.ini
```

The URL has been normalized and the directory traversal exploit has been removed before the GET request is sent to the server. This is possible to overcome with command line tools, such as curl by using the "--path-as-is" flag.

**Is there a way to override this functionality in Firefox/Chrome so that the pages can be pulled from inside of a browser?**

*This is easy for me to reproduce with curl, but harder for the dev team to visualize the issue. When they attempt to do this in their browsers, they are just given a 404 response and assume the code is secure.*

Comment: There are many comments to be made about the source of the problem: 1) devs only trust what they see in the browser and not automated testing? 2) devs are doing manual testing? 3) devs can't visualise the problem if presented in `curl`? 4) have you tried other browsers? older versions of Firefox?

Comment: I agree that this is not the root of the problem. However, it is a temporary measure that is necessary right now as this team becomes more security aware through training and experience. Older browsers are against company policy and can not be installed.

Comment: I'm interested in this problem because I cannot find a setting that changes the behaviour, or any other results from searching, but I'm not sure that this is a security question. This is a FF/Chrome settings question.

Comment: You probably can't stop the browsers from rewriting the URL. What you could do is replace `/` with `%2f` which may or may not be parsed differently by the server.

Comment: @Arminius I imagine the developer tools would allow you to send a request directly.